# How to space images vertically so they always fill the screen

Tags: html, css

Ok, so I have a site that is already responsive to fill the screen height and width. I want to create a vertical div containing 5 images on the right side. I want the 5 images to stay the aspec that they are but going from a 16:9 screen to a 4:3 they are not spreading apart to fill the area vertically or visa verse. Hopefully I'm explaining this correctly.

Right now the images are just staying as is. So on a laptop, only 4 show and the fifth is disappearing off the page, then when I go to a 4:3 screen the images are not spreading apart to fill the empty space at the bottom.

Hopefully someone can under stand what I'm trying to do and lend a hand.

Thanks

Comment: give us some code, to see what you done :)

Comment: I'm not really the greatest at this stuff, I've just tried all sorts of max and min heights of 100% for the div. I've tried using the code from fluid images and I just can't seem to make it work. Currently I just have the 5 images inside a div that has no css to go with it.

Comment: it is not clear enough, size of image for instance ....

Comment: OK, but could you share the code? Without it, it's difficult help you.

http://http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ok, the images are 123w x 94h.

`<div id="thumbimgs">
<BR><BR>
<img class="centered" src="/images/current.png">
<BR>
<img class="centered" src="/images/current.png">
<BR>
<img class="centered" src="/images/current.png">
<BR>
<img class="centered" src="/images/current.png">
<BR>
<img class="centered" src="/images/current.png">
</div>

.centered {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit in response to comment: try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjylJ

body, html{
  height:100%;

}

.img-wrapper > img{
  height:100px;
  }

.img-wrapper{
  width:10%;
  height:20%;
  }

---

you can use percents on containing div.
image will keep aspect ratio if you give it width 100% and allow it to set its own height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sDAHF

```
  .img-wrapper > img{
    width:100%;
   }

 .img-wrapper{
   width:10%;
  display:inline-block;
  height:100%;
  }
```

Comment: That's kinda what I'm going for but the images need to be stacked vertically and then have space between them when the height is larger than the space they are in.

Comment: That's getting closer but they are not filling the height when views on a 4:3 monitor. Since I'm under an NDA I can't share the link to what I'm doing but I can share the theme I'm using. Slash WP theme. The main page has a thumbnail scroller on the right side. I want to have that with just 5 static images that will spread apart and get closer together when viewing on a widescreen or fullscreen screen. If that makes sense...

Comment: by fill the height, you mean top image starts at top of page and bottom image ends at bottom of page? the bottom image is currently not pinned to bottom if that's what you mean.  can you give me monitor dimensions in pixels?

Comment: I don't want the images to stretch, just space apart evenly from top to bottom to fill the section. My displays are (laptop)1366x768 and (desktop) 1280x1024

Comment: here is a different approach using display:table. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zuHKA.  it does not solve your problem 100% but its another direction to explore. also, check out css media querries

Comment: Thank you so much! After playing around with it just a bit, I got what you sent to work perfectly!